# How to perform inline edit in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview

I'm new to MVC. I'm trying to update the data's in the grid. how to do inline edit (Update| Cancel) similar to asp.net gridview.. try to do without jQuery. Please give me suggestions/links on the same. 
[image]

Comment: You can find inline jquery grid online (third party.)

Comment: @AsifRaza Can find that(using datatables)..will we able to achieve without that.

Comment: Its depend on your functionality, before use it go for first pros & cons.